# how to update kendo ui components for using MultiColumnComboBox

Tags: kendo-asp.net-mvc, razor-pages

I tried to use MultiColumnCombo in my exactly like the demo in this link :https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/multicolumncombobox/index .
But it seems that the version of my kendo is not support this component .I need t know if it is a version problem or something else and if the problem is version how to update my telerik in a way that other used components stay healthy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Telerik Upgrade Project Wizard to update your MVC project to the latest version of Telerik UI for ASP.NET MVC which includes the MultiColumnComboBox.

You can find more information in this article https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/vs-integration/upgrade-wizard.

Prior the upgrade please read the release notes so that you get familiar what's new is added to the latest versions: https://www.telerik.com/support/whats-new/aspnet-mvc/release-history